# Multiple file upload with a loop

Tags: php, database, upload

I currently have this script where users (using a form where they can upload up to seven images) can upload multiple images to a folder and the image name to my database, without any success. Please help.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { $ref_49 = $_POST['ref_49'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $rent_sell = $_POST['rent_sell'];
    $heading = $_POST['heading'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $limitedtextarea = $_POST['limitedtextarea'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $where = $_POST['where'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $bedroom = $_POST['bedroom'];
    $bathroom = $_POST['bathroom'];
    $garages = $_POST['garages'];
    $carports = $_POST['carports'];
    $granny_flat = $_POST['granny_flat'];
    $ref_99 = $_POST['ref_99'];
    $fulldesc = $_POST['full_desc'];

    if ($ref_99=="") {
    $full_ad = "yes";
    } else {
    $full_ad = "no";
    }
    $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
     mkdir("gallery/" . $_POST["name"], 0777); 

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) 
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]['name'];
    // strip file_name of slashes
    $file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("'", "", $file_name);
    // $copy = copy($_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['tmp_name'], "gallery/" . $_POST["name"] . "/" . $file_name);

    if ((($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["type"] == "image/gif") 
      || ($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
      || ($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) 
      && ($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["size"] < 200000000)) 
    {
        if ($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["error"] > 0) 
        {
            $message = "Return Code: " . $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO property (

                    name, contact, email, type_of_listing, rent_sell, address, prop_desc, area, price, main_image, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5, image_6, heading, bathroom, bedroom, garages, carports, granny_flat, full_description, full_ad, 49_ref, 99_ref, listed 

                ) VALUES (

                    '{$name}', '{$contact}', '{$email}', '{$type}', '{$rent_sell}', '{$address}', '{$limitedtextarea}', '{$where}', '{$price}', '{$photo_1}', '{$photo_2}', '{$photo_3}', '{$photo_4}', '{$photo_5}', '{$photo_6}', '{$photo_7}', '{$heading}', '{$bathroom}', '{$bedroom}', '{$garages}', '{$carports}', '{$granny_flat}', '{$fulldesc}', '{$full_ad}', 'ref_49_{$ref_49}', 'ref_99_{$ref_99}', ''
                )";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

            if (file_exists("gallery/" . $_POST["name"] . "/" . $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["name"])) 
            {
                $message = "<h3>" . $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["name"] . " already exists.</h3>";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["tmp_name"], "gallery/" . $_POST["name"] . "/" . $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["name"]);
                $message = "File: " . $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]["name"] . " uploaded.";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "<h3>Invalid file or no file selected.</h3><br />• Only JPEG OR GIF allowed.<br />• Size limited may not exceed 200KB.<br /><a href = \"local_artist.php\">Return</a>";
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: A good place to start is to explain the problem.  Error messages?  What isn't working?

Comment: Sorry steve it works fine if I upload all seven files, but as soon as I decide to only upload one or two files I get the $message telling me no file was selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of things going wrong here.  Have you tried to break this up into pieces? Are you sure the DB is connecting? Are you sure php has access to write to the directories it's attempting to write to? Are you sure those directories exist...etc. etc.

Comment out the vast majority of the code, and start testing all the components piece by piece, or wrap stuff in try/catch and see what errors are produced.

[edit]
If the problem only occurs when you upload < 7 files then the problem is in that you've hard coded a 7 into your loop!

Loop through how many files are actually being uploaded, not a fixed number.

Assuming they're all being named sequentially (and starting at 0) you can test for the existence of your hashed FILE value in the loop and just keep ingesting until it comes up null (probably good to add a limiter to make sure it can't go on for ever)

something like this...

[edit 2] modified the condition to include a test for file size

```
for($i=0;  $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i] && $_FILES['uploadFile' . $i]['size'] > 0 && $i<100 ; $i++){
  try{
    //do your upload stuff here
  }catch(e){}
}
```

[EDIT]
To modify your page to include a dynamic number of fields do this:

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RjcHY/2/

Click the plus and minus buttons on the right side to see how it works. I made it so that it's naming the file buttons as per your php's expectations.

Comment: Dr. Dredel, yes my database connect fine, I edited the code and put the entire script in so you can see what I did, like I said to steve it works fine when I upload all seven pictures, but when I decide to only upload two or three, my $message is displayed that no files were selected.

Comment: Haha, ok thank you, but if I loop to 100 then I must have a 100 file upload fields?. I tried your code just change 100 to 6 to accomadate for only 7 file upload fields in my form, it works, but again I sitting with the problem I must fill all the upload fields otherwise I get the message "Invalid file or no file selected", maybe a for each loop but unsure how to implement the code.

Comment: Ah... I see. Ok 2 things. 1) you should modify your page to offer people only the number of file upload fields they actually use. Let them click on some [+] button to insert more fields if they need them.  On the server you should modify the if statement to include a check to see if the file that's being uploaded actually has content... I'll edit my solution again...

Comment: as to the 100... no... look at the condition... as SOON as $_FILES['uploadFile' + i] is false (meaning you don't have an element called uploadFileX in your list of uploaded fields), it stops the loop. The only reason I add the 100 limit is as a vague protection against something going wrong and this getting stuck in an infinite loop... it's not likely, but it's a simple precaution just in case.

Comment: Dr. Dredel I thank you. Your the man. It works. Thank you for your time and effort you really help getting a big stone out of my path. I would love to use your idea of the [+] button to add the fields if the user prefer more upload fields, but to be honest I have no idea how to write the code for it.

Comment: you're welcome! don't forget to upvote my answer (and/or give me the green checkmark).  The [+] could just be javascript in your page which would alter the innerHTML of the div that has your File inputs.

Comment: Where can I upvote/green checkmark your answer and do you now the javascript to get the [+] mark

Comment: next to my answer there is a big 0 with an up and down arrow above and beneath it... click the up arrow (for all the answers that you think merit it) and click the check mark beneath the down arrow for the answer that you feel answers your question.  This is how points are earned on Stack.  As to the javascript, I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with common tasks like file uploading, write some library for handling those tasks and call necessary function wherever needed . If you create an uploader class file , you can simply invoke one of the methods you created to handle file uploads .

Here i will give you a Uploader class

```
<?php

//Save file as Uploader.php
//File Uploading Class

class Uploader
{
private $destinationPath;
private $errorMessage;
private $extensions;
private $allowAll;
private $maxSize;
private $uploadName;
private $seqnence;
public $name='Uploader';
public $useTable =false;

function setDir($path){
$this->destinationPath = $path;
$this->allowAll = false;
}

function allowAllFormats(){
$this->allowAll = true;
}

function setMaxSize($sizeMB){
$this->maxSize = $sizeMB * (1024*1024);
}

function setExtensions($options){
$this->extensions = $options;
}

function setSameFileName(){
$this->sameFileName = true;
$this->sameName = true;
}
function getExtension($string){
$ext = "";
try{
$parts = explode(".",$string);
$ext = strtolower($parts[count($parts)-1]);
}catch(Exception $c){
$ext = "";
}
return $ext;
}

function setMessage($message){
$this->errorMessage = $message;
}

function getMessage(){
return $this->errorMessage;
}

function getUploadName(){
return $this->uploadName;
}
function setSequence($seq){
$this->imageSeq = $seq;
}

function getRandom(){
return strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:iConfused')).rand(1111,9999).rand(11,99).rand(111,999);
}
function sameName($true){
$this->sameName = $true;
}
function uploadFile($fileBrowse){
$result = false;
$size = $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["size"];
$name = $_FILES[$fileBrowse]["name"];
$ext = $this->getExtension($name);
if(!is_dir($this->destinationPath)){
$this->setMessage("Destination folder is not a directory ");
}else if(!is_writable($this->destinationPath)){
$this->setMessage("Destination is not writable !");
}else if(empty($name)){
$this->setMessage("File not selected ");
}else if($size>$this->maxSize){
$this->setMessage("Too large file !");
}else if($this->allowAll || (!$this->allowAll && in_array($ext,$this->extensions))){

if($this->sameName==false){
$this->uploadName = $this->imageSeq."-".substr(md5(rand(1111,9999)),0,8).$this->getRandom().rand(1111,1000).rand(99,9999).".".$ext;
}else{
$this->uploadName= $name;
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileBrowse]["tmp_name"],$this->destinationPath.$this->uploadName)){
$result = true;
}else{
$this->setMessage("Upload failed , try later !");
}
}else{
$this->setMessage("Invalid file format !");
}
return $result;
}

function deleteUploaded(){
unlink($this->destinationPath.$this->uploadName);
}

}

?>
```

Using Uploader.php

```
<?php

$uploader = new Uploader();
$uploader->setDir('uploads/images/');
$uploader->setExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')); //allowed extensions list//
$uploader->setMaxSize(.5); //set max file size to be allowed in MB//

if($uploader->uploadFile('txtFile')){ //txtFile is the filebrowse element name //
$image = $uploader->getUploadName(); //get uploaded file name, renames on upload//

}else{//upload failed
$uploader->getMessage(); //get upload error message
}


?>
```

For handling multiple uploads , ex 3 images uploading 
repeat the block as follows

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){

    $uploader->setExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')); //allowed extensions list//
    $uploader->setMaxSize(.5); //set max file size to be allowed in MB//
    $uploader->setSequence($i);
    if($uploader->uploadFile('txtFile'.$i)){ //txtFile is the filebrowse element name //
       $image = $uploader->getUploadName(); //get uploaded file name, renames on upload//

    }else{//upload failed
     $uploader->getMessage(); //get upload error message
    }

}

?>
```

in above example , file browse components are named as txtFile1,txtFile2,txtFile3
Hope you will understand my explanation .

Comment: Thank You Kiran going to try it out now, when i use your code how am I going to send the data to the database while uploading the images

Comment: $image = $uploader->getUploadName();  this line gives you the uploaded file name . ie $image . You can use this variable in mysql query (insert) . or keep all teh uploaded files names in an array  like $images[] = $uploader->getUploadName(); loop through array and execute an insert query

Comment: Hi Kiran, tried your code but failed miserbly, I am a unsure what to do with your code, sorry I really a beginner, I saved the file as uploader.php (seperate file) and put the code thats under your comment "For handling multiple uploads , ex 3 images uploading repeat the block as follows...." in my original page and add a include(uploader.php) but I get the error that $uploader is undefined???